# Entities Given same ID

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm suddenly seeing errors which I can so far only explain by the datastore creating entities with the same ID/key. This seems (and I'm hoping like crazy) that this is associated with a just one entity group.

It started happening about 90 mins ago, when we were getting more hits/second (12) than I've ever seen, so there is a good chance that this is related to a second instance spinning up - the dashboard doesn't show a second instance, though.

Anyone else seeing anything weird? If so, please let me know to save me trying to figure out how my code could be failing with multiple instances.

Comment: This is not exactly how stackoverflow works.. You have to be very specific on the questions and answers, because you have to start accepting more answers. Questions without accepting answers will keep popping up until they are solved.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/142717 read this for more..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem ended up being due to a user who posted a link which included a session ID. Other users who clicked that link got the same session, and so all of them used the same entity referenced by the ID in that session. I'm adding logic so if the referrer is not my site, the presented session ID is ignored.

So the answer is that I WASN'T getting duplicate IDs from the datastore. If anyone else thinks this is causing their bug in the future, you're probably wrong (although make sure you understand the comments about different entity types and parenting).

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are confusing numerical [IDs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_by_id) with the String representation of the Key. The key is always unique per entity in your datastore, but It's not the same for IDs. They are not guaranteed that going to be the same. Also for the same types, if they are parented, then it's only guaranteed to be unique for entities that have the same parent and not on the model type level.

Comment: You are right, but that wasn't my problem - these were entities of the same type, for which IDs will be unique.

Comment: @FoxyLad This doesn't matter if they are the same type. If they are parented, then the ID is not guaranteed to be the same.